# What algorithm would blend multiple images that has same scene except one object on different positions in every image?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I want to blend multiple photo shots of same scene but only one object is in different position on every shot. I want to know what kind of algorithm would give desired results. Here is an example [image]

Comment: In practice, your images won't be identical.  If they where identical other than the figure, you could do a simple pairwise xor to find the mask of the dude -- `(a xor b & b xor c)` is the xor of the dude in b, and similarly for the dude in c, then xor them both on a, and done.  In practice, your images are not going to be identical other than the dude.  So it would be easier to simply select the dude in the 3 pictures, find some common points between the pictures to produce a transformation so the dude is in the right spot, then clone the dude over to one of the pictures.

Comment: How can i simply select the dude with code?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you are looking for is called [**Image Fusion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_fusion). There are many methods that do this, but it is still a fairly active research idea. Based on the images you have, you should select the one that performs the best. Because your images will have imperfections and lighting, shadowing differences this is way beyond than a simple cut and paste.

Here is a little more information and some algorithm explanations: [Image Fusion by Image Blending](http://www.imgfsr.com/ifsr_ImageFusion.pdf).

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of image fusion. I even once implemented image fusion with laplacian pyramids. What i can't find here is what kind of image fusion would serve in my purpose? I made a few google search however couldn't find anything useful yet.

Comment: That's the point. It is degree of 'do-ability' depends on the specific set of images. There are a lot of techniques in the imaging research community but nothing works perfect. The answer to your question, "How can I select the dude with code?", is not as simple as the question itself.

Comment: So what do you think about getting user input. Lets say user will paint a mask on the part of image that is different. In this picture for example user will paint over the dude. Do you think it is easier to find a way to refine that selection paint to make it look perfect?